# I can't run a script python in Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to install this script( https://github.com/SpEcHiDe/AnyDLBot)
on my server, but I was surprised that I cannot run any Python script and this error message appears to me every time I run the Python script :

```
(VENV) root@Hermania:/datadrive/AnyDLBot# python3 -m anydlbot                Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/datadrive/AnyDLBot/anydlbot/__main__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pyrogram import Client
  File "/datadrive/AnyDLBot/VENV/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyrogram/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from .client import *
  File "/datadrive/AnyDLBot/VENV/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyrogram/client/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from .client import Client
  File "/datadrive/AnyDLBot/VENV/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyrogram/client/client.py", line 40, in <module>
    from pyrogram.client.methods.password.utils import compute_check
  File "/datadrive/AnyDLBot/VENV/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyrogram/client/methods/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from .bots import Bots
  File "/datadrive/AnyDLBot/VENV/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyrogram/client/methods/bots/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from .answer_callback_query import AnswerCallbackQuery
  File "/datadrive/AnyDLBot/VENV/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyrogram/client/methods/bots/answer_callback_query.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pyrogram.client.ext import BaseClient
  File "/datadrive/AnyDLBot/VENV/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyrogram/client/ext/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from .base_client import BaseClient
  File "/datadrive/AnyDLBot/VENV/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyrogram/client/ext/base_client.py", line 28, in <module>
    from ..parser import Parser
  File "/datadrive/AnyDLBot/VENV/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyrogram/client/parser/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from .parser import Parser
  File "/datadrive/AnyDLBot/VENV/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyrogram/client/parser/parser.py", line 23, in <module>
    from .html import HTML
  File "/datadrive/AnyDLBot/VENV/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyrogram/client/parser/html.py", line 109, in <module>
    class HTML:
  File "/datadrive/AnyDLBot/VENV/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyrogram/client/parser/html.py", line 110, in HTML
    def __init__(self, client: Union["pyrogram.BaseClient", None]):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 552, in __getitem__
    dict(self.__dict__), parameters, _root=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 512, in __new__
    for t2 in all_params - {t1} if not isinstance(t2, TypeVar)):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 512, in <genexpr>
    for t2 in all_params - {t1} if not isinstance(t2, TypeVar)):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 190, in __subclasscheck__
    self._eval_type(globalns, localns)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 177, in _eval_type
    eval(self.__forward_code__, globalns, localns),
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'pyrogram' has no attribute 'BaseClient'
```

For your information, I changed versions of Python, but I faced the same problem ☹️☹️☹️☹️☹️☹️

Comment: Generally speaking, debugging other peoples' software is outside of our scope. If you want to fix this yourself, load a debugger, put a breakpoint on the line referring to `Union["pyrogram.BaseClient", None]`, and inspect. Don't expect someone here to do that for you; if you want a question we'll answer here, you need to build a standalone [mre] that reproduces the specific error underlying the bug and include it _in the question itself_. Better, file a ticket in `AnyDLBot`'s bug tracker.

Comment: Generally, this kind of error points to problems with your local install.  In this case I would bet that your installed version of `pyrogram` is different than the one used to write this `AnyDLBot` script.